# A polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials

> Is it true that if a polynomial $f(x)$ takes integer values for every integer $x$ then its coefficients are integers?

I believe that it is. I just need a **hint** as to how I can prove or disprove this and just in case you were wondering this is *not* a homework problem.

Comment: **Hint** Consider  $\displaystyle\,{x\choose n} = \dfrac{x(x-1)\cdots (x-n+1)}{n!}\ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's false. Take for example $x(x-1)/2$

Comment: What would be a sufficient condition for a polynomial to have integer coefficeints?

Comment: You could also use the example y = $x(x + 1)(x + 2) / 3$. Notice that if $x$ is divisible by 3, then y will be an integer. If x is not divisible by 3, then either $x + 1$ or $x + 2$ are.